# Администрирование в GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish, администрирование

Здравствуйте.
Как в **GlassFish** запустить сборщик мусора насильно?
Как следить из админ-панели **GlassFish** за утечкой памяти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Насильно запускать сборку мусора не требуется никогда.
2. Следить за утечкой памяти из админ-панели тоже не надо. Используте [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com) или [VisualVM](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/61857).

Comment: Ух-ты, спасибо. Буду осваивать )

Comment: Про пункт один я немного слукавил. На самом деле, насильно выполнять сборку можно из любопытства. Практической же пользы всё-таки нет.

Comment: Ну все равно в обоих случаях смысл такой же. Спасибо )))