# Процент занятой памяти в Java-приложении?

Tags: java

Написал программу на java. Сначала она работает нормально. Но всегда рано или поздно падает out of memory exception. Скорее всего можно задать большое количество используемой памяти. Но это ведь не решение проблемы. Я не могу понять, в какой момент начинает съедаться так много памяти. Можно ли как-то вывести в java-приложении количество использованной (выделенной?) памяти?

Comment: Все програмные проверки используемой памяти неточны. Ищите там, где у вас в циклах/потоках создаются объекты. А вообще для этого обычно используют профайлеры. С другой стороны необязательно мониторить состояние памяти из самой жава программы. Можно из ОС. В *никсах это проще простого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, это поможет. У меня были проблемы с утечкой памяти и большой загруженностью процессора. Тут мне помогли. [Вот ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/13284/%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-glassfish). Эти системы работают не только с серверами приложений. А со всем. Я пользовался VisualVM. @cy6erGn0m тоже посоветовал это использовать.

Comment: Спасибо. Должно помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте дамп памяти. Можно также запустить Java-машину с опцией -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError чтобы машина сделала дамп в момент крэша. Этот дамп можно будет посмотреть с помощью visualvm и понять, что заняло столько места.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте лог-файл, куда вносятся любые операции, результат которых отнимает память(создание классов и т.д.).

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println(1 - r.freeMemory() / r.totalMemory());
```

Comment: Этот код выводит всё нормально. Даже видно, в какой момент срабатывает сборщик мусора. Но для отладки помогает слабо.